# Is it correct to place link tags outside the html tag like Google recommends?

Tags: html

I have done a lot of research on this subject and the answers I've found here are too old or confusing. Besides, we're in 2017 and things might have changed. Now my doubt is: Google says that, in some cases, we can put a link tag outside the html tag, like this:

[image: screen shot of the page speed insights]

I'm an experienced web developer and I already know the standard positions for link tags. But I didn't know we could place a link tag outside the html tag. My question is:
Is that practice correct? If not, why would Google recommend a bad practice?
By the way, this where I found that Google's recommendation:
[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever its telling you, I very much doubt its that.  Where on that page is that recommendation?

Comment: Where, on the page you linked to, does it say that? It's also invalid HTML.

Comment: The page you linked doesn't mention `link` tags in the main text at all. In the two examples it gives where `link` tags are seen, neither is outside `html`. This isn't surprising as it's not valid to have an element outside `html`.

Comment: I replaced the code with an actual image of the page. It's in Portuguese because I couldn't find a way to translate. By the way, it would be nice to know why people downvote almost all questions I ask. I can't ask better questions than that because the other ones don't interest me. I wanna know about this and this only. Thanks again.

Comment: You should only read non-English stuff on the internet if you can't understand most of it, inferring from your comment, your English is pretty good, so you should stick to that.

Comment: Can't you see that red rectangle on the image? How can that be a translation problem?

Comment: @Regis Because when you change the language back to English, everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It only tells you that in non-English versions of that page (I tried Spanish, Polski and Arabic), could be an error with the translation or something like that; change the language to English and everything is OK.

*second thoughts, this would be more proper for a comment.*

Answer (score 1):

Is it valid HTML, no. Does it work in browsers, yes, and is effectively functionally identical to placing the link element just before the `</body>` tag.

However, putting a stylesheet link even at the end of the body element has only been HTML valid since HTML 5.2. Prior to that, it wasn't valid outside the head element, which would have had a different effect from a page speed perspective.

It follows then, that until recently there was no way to HTML validly do what the Google page was recommending, and it's likely that only the English language version of the PageSpeed Insights page has been updated since a valid way became possible.